# How do i do transformations in HTML Canva?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an assignment for university to reproduce an emoji figure in html canva context 2D. This is what I have so far and in main I try to scale it up and on other parts move stuff around so it makes sense but all the transformations don't seem to work, nothing changes on the image. 
I know this is pretty basic but I don't know why it doesn't work so let me know if you can help. thanks!

```
function enter(dx, dy, sx, sy, a){
    this.save();
    this.rotate(a);
    this.translate(dx, dy);
    this.scale(sx, sy);
}

function leave(){
    this.restore();
}

function nose(){
    let p = new Path2D();
    p.moveTo(62, 36);
    p.lineTo(66, 36);
    p.quadraticCurveTo(64, 38, 62, 36);
    return p;
}

function mouth(){
    let p = new Path2D();
    p.moveTo(59, 40);
    p.quadraticCurveTo(64, 42, 69, 40);
    p.quadraticCurveTo(64, 47, 59, 40);
    return p;
}

function face(c){
    let p_nose = nose();
    let p_mouth = mouth();

    c.fillStyle = "seagreen";
    c.fill(p_nose);
    c.stroke(p_nose);
    c.fillStyle = "crimson";
    c.fill(p_mouth);
    c.stroke(p_mouth);
}

function main(){
    let canvas_element = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    let gc = canvas_element.getContext("2d");
    gc.enter = enter;
    gc.leave = leave;
    gc.face = face;

    face(gc)
    gc.enter(0,0,100,100,0);
    leave(gc);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified a bit your code to keep this example small.
You need to translate, rotate and scale before you draw your objects

```js
function enter(c, dx, dy, sx, sy, a) {
  c.save();
  c.rotate(a);
  c.translate(dx, dy);
  c.scale(sx, sy);
}

function leave(c) {
  c.restore();
}

function mouth() {
  let p = new Path2D();
  p.moveTo(59, 40);
  p.quadraticCurveTo(64, 42, 69, 40);
  p.quadraticCurveTo(64, 47, 59, 40);
  return p;
}

function face(c) {
  let p_mouth = mouth();
  c.fillStyle = "crimson";
  c.fill(p_mouth);
  c.stroke(p_mouth);
}

function main() {
  let canvas_element = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  let gc = canvas_element.getContext("2d");

  enter(gc, -150, -150, 5, 5, 0.2);
  face(gc)
  leave(gc);
}

main()
```

```html
<canvas id=myCanvas>
```

Comment: it worked, thanks! so if i have to do the transformations before drawing the objects, what would be the best way to organize objects? like i have the gc element for the face do i create another one for the body? is that the right way to do it?

Comment: best way to organize objects is debatable, just get it to work then refactor to suit your needs... Don't forget to +1 and accept the answer